# XMPP Push Notification for iOS chat app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xmpp, google-talk

I'm creating Google talk client for iOS. I have **BOSH server** (used node-xmpp-bosh) and iOS client (used xmppframework). The iOS client connect through this BOSH server.

Now, how can I made a push notification to client (possibly from Bosh server) whenever there is incoming chat message or friend request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node-xmpp-bosh actually provides for exactly this sort of use-case. The BOSH server is an instance of an [eventpipe](https://github.com/dhruvbird/eventpipe) that lets you pipe events to/from the BOSH server to your custom modules/plugins. This is where you can code up the logic for the push notification service.

The advantage of doing this on the BOSH server is that you can support every XMPP service and not just the one that you control the XMPP server for. i.e. You can provide this functionality for google talk, facebook, jabber.org, etc...

Disclosure: I'm one of the authors of node-xmpp-bosh.

Comment: thanks! i ended listening on "response" event

`bosh_server.on("response", function(stanza, stream) {});`

is this right approach to listen on "response" event? or any better event I should listen on?

So much thanks for creating node-xmpp-bosh :)

Comment: @ThantThet That's perfect. You might want to read the docs. of EventPipe to see how to stop event propagation (something you can't do with a simple EventEmitter). You're most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

To support Push notification you need a special change on the server. We have developed that module for ejabberd (this is something you can see in TextOne and OneTeam).
The details to implement push notification yourself is available on:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Since i don't have access to GTalk server. Is it possible to develop module BOSH server?